Creating a huawei Watch or LiteOS App with DevEco Studio - Device Type Unavailable and Sample Not Working with Latest Version (3.1.1)
I'm trying to develop an app for huawei watch  and LiteOS using DevEco Studio, but I'm encountering some issues. The device type for WatchOS and LiteOS doesn't seem to be available, and the sample provided in the documentation isn't syncing  with the latest version of DevEco Studio (3.1.1). Could someone please guide me on how to create an app for huawei Watch and LiteOS using DevEco Studio?  Here's a screenshot illustrating the issue:


basically i want to start with a hello word app.

I'm facing the same issue, I found https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/harmonyos-guides-V3/lite-wearable-experience-0000000000622606-V3
But still trying to get the device type wearable

I am also just started looking into the Huawei Lite Wearable app development using the Dev Eco Studio. I think I have crossed this step now.
You have to select the "[Lite]Empty Activity" option in the Create Project Menu.
Refer below snap.

Hope my answer is helpful.
